# ASP.Net MVC - MapRoute - RegEx

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to use a RegEx to create a new route in ASP.Net MVC 4.
I want to redirect to a specific controller and action when the url contains one letter between slashes and a word:

http://www.myurl.com/a/something/anotherthing/?mykeyword=.....

My current route is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
             "MyRoute",
             "{*something}",
             new { controller = "mycontroller", action = "myaction" },
             new { theregex = @".*/a/.*?mykeyword=.*" });
```

But I never go into mycontroller/myaction. I'm always redirect to the default route.

Can someone tell me what is wrong in the regex?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you map this route before any other? There's a precedence order, this kind of route must stay before any other.

Comment: You've set a constraint on the route parameter `theregex`, but your actual route parameter is `something`. Is this just a error from redacting the code for public consumption?

Comment: Also, you can't match a query string in the route as it's not taken into account for routing purposes.

Comment: Indeed, I've completely forgotten that the query string was not taken for the routing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
https?:\/\/[^\/]*\/a\/[^?]*\?mykeyword=
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dF0lJ7/1)

---

String literals for use in programs:

```
@"https?:\/\/[^\/]*\/a\/[^?]*\?mykeyword="
```